# Damaged luggage compensation

Tags: emirates, damaged-luggage

We used Emirates for our travel and the airline delayed the luggage (delivered the next day at our residence) but delivered it in a severely damaged condition.

They are offering compensation which is about 50% of the value of the entire set we purchased (set of three, the largest one got damaged by the airline).

We are asking them to replace the damaged suitcase with an equivalent or better compensation amount so that we can buy the largest suitcase on its own (their offer is about $10 lower).

Should we accept their compensation or do we have other options? They have indicated that they cannot compensate more than what they offer now.

Thank you. If anyone can help advise.

Comment: *Their offer is about $10 lower*. As hopeless as it sounds, take it. Compensation and your chances depend upon a lot of factors. The biggest one you didn't mention; Where did it happen? What's your nationality? Where did the flight originate from and where did it land. Its not a black and white thing unfortunately. Obviously you do have options, but how much time you want to spend on them is a personal choice. I wouldn't find a `$10` extra claim but many people would. Did you have travel insurance for this flight?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The incident happened on return flight to Delhi. I am an Indian. The flight was Dubai to Delhi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a fair offer. Within $10 is actually quite good and most times replacement costs are not offered and you only get repair costs which makes the suitcase usable but not like new either, so I would take the offer.

In any case, they were clear that it is all that can offer. Since it is so close to the value you expected, it is much less risky to take this rather than push for more.